# How To Set Layout For Android Grid View Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, adapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.nusecond.suredeal.app.R;
import com.nusecond.suredeal.app.suredeal.activity.MainActivity;
import com.nusecond.suredeal.app.suredeal.activity.Promo;
import com.nusecond.suredeal.app.suredeal.pojo.Campaigns;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ns2 on 2/4/16.
 */
public class CustomPromoAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Campaigns> campaigns;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomPromoAdapter(Activity activity, List<Campaigns> campaigns){
        this.activity=activity;
        this.campaigns=campaigns;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return campaigns.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return campaigns.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater==null)
            inflater=(LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView==null)
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.promo_gridlist,null);
        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail1);

        TextView tView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      //  tView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(5, 5));
        Campaigns ca=campaigns.get(position);
        tView.setText(ca.getName());
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(ca.getImage(), imageLoader);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

1. This is My Custom Adapter To Display Images In Grid View.
2. Now I'm Displaying only 4 Images But I need 8.
3. The Text View Also Showing Not Properly.
4. I Don't Know Where I Need To Change I mean In My Adapter Or In My Layout File.
5. I Tried To Set LayoutParms But It Won't Work properly.
6. I'm new To Android Can Any One Help me...
7. Below Is My Layout....

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail1"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

1. I'm Getting The Images And Text From Rest Setver..
2. Below is My Main Layout....

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".suredeal.activity.Promo" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:numColumns="2" >

    </GridView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

1. This is My Main Layout..

---

[This is What I'm Displaying With The Above Code..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWHbW.png)

---

[This is What I'm Trying To Do...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dyjq.png)

---

1. Any Help Thankful To Them.......

---

Comment: First thing first : in your mainLayout GridView declaration you have written android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" where is textView1?? Dude Second Thing: As I can see from the pictures you have provided Your activity contains just a gridView correct? Then Why gridView has android:layout_height="wrap_content" ?? Shouldn't it be android:layout_height="match_parent" ??? Finallyas per the images you have provided I can only see ImageView and TextView below it in each GridView cell :) In your cell xml there are two ImageView's 1.NetworkImageView and 2. imageView1 and both have hardcoded heights

Comment: i suggest you first try testing your app using local resources (images) then if it worked fine switch on remote resources . in your case network delays and download time can effect app

Comment: None of their visibility is invisible or gone :) So what are you expecting ?? Some sort of magic dude? Obviously each cell takes 88+88+height of textview in dp so your cells are much bigger then the one that you showed in images :) And gridview can't accommadate 8 such cells so it is showing only 4 :)

Comment: and for your images use libraries like **Picasso** or **Glide** for easier work on images in local and remote mode.

Comment: Incidentally, most people would now recommend using `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` instead of using a `GridView`. `RecyclerView` is more modern.

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" is in android:id="@+id/textView1" in promo_grid_list Layout@SandeepBhandari